# Victory conditions with the "Limited Range of Influence" option

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In a ten player [Grand Melee](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/casual-formats-2008-08-11), Anthony controls a [Darksteel Reactor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Darksteel%20Reactor) with 20 counters on it.

Anthony has satisfied the trigger condition for Darksteel Reactor. The trigger resolves, and he wins the game. However, with the limited range of influence option, only the person to Anthony's left and right will lose the game. There is now a void on Anthony's left and right, and his range of influence is not reevaluated until the beginning of his next turn. But Anthony never gets another turn because the Reactor will trigger again and again forever.

What happens to Anthony now? Can other turn markers bring opponents into Anthony's range of influence so that they will lose to him? In other words, can the void on his left and right ever be collapsed? If not, has he fallen victim to an infinite loop, forcing a draw by his own victory condition?

Comment: I don't know grand melee, but nowhere in that article it is mentioned that range of influence is only re-evaluated in between turns. Are you sure about that?

Comment: 801.2c The particular players within each player's range of influence are determined as each turn begins.

Comment: @IvoBeckers See Diego's response to your comment. In Grand Melee, more than one player can take a turn at a time. This made me think that Anthony could be released from his loop when a player to his left receives a turn marker. Thus, the loop would not be infinite because it could be broken by other turn markers. But it's possible that the player to Anthony's left could never begin his turn because they must wait for Anthony to finish, and so eventually there would be a true infinite loop. I thought this was too speculative to put in the actual question, so I left it open ended.

Comment: I guess that casting a Time Stop won't help right? The ability would just trigger again in the clean-up step.

Comment: @IvoBeckers Anthony will never even make it to his Cleanup step. He cannot progress his turn at all. He must repeatedly trigger and resolve Darksteel Reactor.

Comment: I am pretty sure that casting Time Stop in response to the trigger would do that.

Comment: @IvoBeckers Yes, I suppose you are right. I should have read Time Stop more carefully (all three words of it).

Comment: @IvoBeckers Time Stop would remove the ability from the stack and send you to the Cleanup Step on that turn, but in the Cleanup Step the trigger would go off again and go back on the stack.

Comment: Would Time Stop ever resolve? Wouldn't the trigger just be placed on the stack on top of Time Stop repeatedly?

Comment: @Gendolkari `603.8. A state-triggered ability doesn't trigger again until the ability has resolved, has been countered, or has otherwise left the stack.`

Comment: It appears the answer is, "any non-standard win condition shouldn't be the basis of a grand melee deck."  Too bad Dark Steel didn't say, "all opponents lose the game" because then the loop wouldn't occur...

Comment: @John With the limited range of influence option, *"all opponents"* means *"all opponents within your range of influence"*. The loop would still occur, because Anthony's range of influence is never reevaluated.

Comment: @John At least you can still use things that make you win (or your opponents lose) just once. If you [search for "you win the game" on gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=+[%22you%20win%20the%20game%22]) you'll see that most of them make you win at the beginning of your upkeep.

Comment: @Jefromi It took me a while to find one that didn't, just so I could ask this question. And I really didn't want to use Cheese.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anthony would force himself to draw that game.

> **801.16.** If the game somehow enters a "loop" of mandatory actions, repeating a sequence of events with no way to stop, the game is a draw for each player who controls an object that's involved in that loop, as well as for each player within the range of influence of any of those players. They leave the game. All remaining players continue to play the game.

Grand Melee is set up so that no matter who the Active Player is any given player is inside only one AP's range of influence<sup>[[807.4d]](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Grand_Melee)</sup>. This is so that you can't have weird things happen like being within the range of influence of 2 different players at 2 different parts of their turn, because Magic doesn't really support, for example, being in both an upkeep and combat step at the same time.

Since there is no way for Anthony to progress any farther in the current turn than the Cleanup Step, the current turn can't end for him. If somehow someones range of influence were allowed to move into him that would then mean he was currently part of 2 separate turns and that just doesn't make sense in Magic.

Comment: Just because it doesn't make sense to be a part of two separate turns doesn't mean Wizards handled it. The relevant rule is: `807.4d A player who receives a turn marker can’t begin his or her turn if any player in the three seats to his or her left has a turn marker.` It is because of that rule that nobody can break Anthony's infinite loop.

Comment: @Rainbolt I probably should explicitly cite that rule, that is what makes sure any player is only in a single AP's range of influence.

Comment: Great. You already had my upvote and accepted answer because it made logical sense. Like you said, it couldn't work any other way without breaking the game.

Comment: It's a little unfortunate that the rules of Grand Melee have to be such that a card which literally says "you win the game" turns into "you cannot win the game".